# Extract URLs with lxml

Tags: python, parsing, extract, lxml

I've scraped some HTML into a large txt file (~50k lines), and would like to extract a specific set of URLs. The URL that I'm after is in one of two patterns:

First

```
<div class="pic">
  <a href="https://www.site.com/joesmith"><img alt="Joe Smith" class="person_image" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/photos.site.com/medium_jpg?12345678"></a>
</div>
```

Second

```
<div class="name">
  <a href="https://www.site.com/joesmith">Joe Smith</a>
</div>
```

The text that I need is `https://www.site.com/joesmith`. I'm working with the lxml for the first time, and I'm having a hard time getting this together.

Here's my code

```
from lxml import etree
from io import StringIO

def read(filename):
  file = open(filename, 'r')
  text = file.read()
  file.close()
  out = unicode(text, errors='ignore')
  return out

def parse(filename):
  data = read(filename)
  parser = etree.HTMLParser()
  tree = etree.parse(StringIO(data), parser)
  result = etree.tostring(tree.getroot(), pretty_print=True, method='HTML')
  urls = result.findall('<div class="name">')
  return urls
```

I've tried this code with both findall and findtext, and either way the result is the same, **"AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'findall'"**. I have confirmed that 'result' is a string with `type()`.

Am I headed on the right path to extract the URL? How should I address this attribute error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if the HTML based trees support XPath ( I suspect they do). In that case you could simply do

```
urls = tree.xpath('//div[@class="pics"]/a/@href') + 
       tree.xpath('//div[@class="name"]/a/@href')
```

Comment: This is great, I didn't even know about xpath. Thanks!